# Configurable Product

Tags: magento-enterprise, configurable-product

I have created a configurable product on my magento store and created different simple product so I can associated them under my configurable product.

It has different SKU and it is fine I want that functionality but how can I make the **specification** different everytime user chooses different variants?

Depends on "Storage" or "Processor"

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "specification different everytime"? Give an example

Comment: Whenever a user click and select the storage attribute and select the process attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this out of the box, but there are are least two extensions which does this, a free and a paid one. I recommend the paid one :-)

The free one is this:
https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple

Comment: what is the link of the paid one?
Is this compatible using magento ee 1.4 version?

Comment: We don't advertise paid extensions here, but the name is Better Configurable Produts